# How to send a custom help PM

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Trying to make a custom help command with discord.py rewrite so far i have this

```
@bot.command(pass_contex = true)
  async def help(ctx):    
    author = ctx.message.author

    embed.set_author(name="Help")
    embed.add_field(name="!Commands" , value= "Type '!' + a name starting with a capital" , inline=False)
    await bot.send_message(author, embed=embed)
```

but this gives an error about bot not being about to send a message

Comment: The `help` command is already implemented by `Bot` to use the [`HelpFormatter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpFormatter) class.  If possible, you should subclass `HelpFormatter` and change the `format` method.  The default implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/discord/ext/commands/formatter.py#L279).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some misspelling issues

```
@bot.command(pass_contex = true)
```

should be

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
```

and you never actually made the embed

```
author = ctx.message.author
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_author(name="Help")
embed.add_field(name="!Commands" , value= "Type '!' + a name starting with a capital" , inline=False)
await ctx.send(author, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Yeah I had the embed in there just higher up in the code, now this just gives me this error "AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'"

Comment: Is there a way to have that pm to a user ?

Comment: @Excelerated Sure, you can add `user:discord.Member` to the parameters of your function (`async def help(ctx,user:discord.Member):`) and then do something like `await ctx.send(user, embed=embed)`

Comment: Now when ever someone uses the !help command it just adds the add_fields again and again so it looks like this https://gyazo.com/72d3359a4f733b1e434d83923a898c64

Comment: You have to create the embed inside the function (`embed = discord.Embed()`)

Comment: Thanks for all your help dude. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, to mark to anyone in the future reading this with a similar problem you can mark the thread as 'answered' by [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)